# I am trying to get my image to show on webpage

Tags: html, image

What do I have to do to get my images to show up on my webpage. I am trying to put the images in my html document. The box shows up but not the image. This the code `<img scr="smile.jpg" width="120" height="90"/>` I have not put the web page on the internet yet.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD> 
    <TITLE> Tay first Web page </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1 ALIGN="center"> Why do I want to learn to code? </H1>
    <P> I want to learn to code because it will help me develop the skills I need in web development and game development. My goal is to learn how to code in many different languages. It is amazing to me to be able to create something from scratch and making it into your vision.</P>
<H2 ALIGN="center"> Why is coding fun? </H2>
    <P> Computer coding is <STRONG> wonderful.</STRONG> You get to make a web page with whatever info you want and add so many things to it to make it mind blowing.There are colours, images, flash, and you can even make a video game if you wanted too. The possibilities are endless and mind blowing.</P>
<H3 ALIGN="center"> How can coding be important in the real world? </H3>
    <P> <EM>Technology</EM> is everywhere and is constantly changing. <MARK>Computers</MARK> are so intertwined in our lives. People view web pages all the time and are looking at code everyday. Being able to code can get you a job if you are efficient with different languages.
    <P><STRONG>These are the best consoles ever!!!!</STRONG></P>
<UL>
    <LI>N64</LI>
    <LI>SEGA GENESIS</LI>
    <LI>XBOX</LI>
    <LI>XBOX 360</LI>
</UL>
<TABLE BORDER="1">
<TR><TD>First</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Second</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Third</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<IMG SRC="smile.jpg" WIDTH="120" HEIGHT="90"/>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Could you put up more of the code, plus the image format or name might be wrong

Comment: yes I can. <img src="smile.jpg" width="120" height="90"/> This image does not show but this image does <img src="http://www.htmldog.com/badge1.gif" width="120" height="90" alt="HTML Dog"/>

Comment: <img src="smile.jpg" width="120" height="90"/> should work if the image is called smile.jpg and is in the same folder as myfirstpage.html ....or maybe the problem could be in the rest of the html

Comment: I just checked again its in the same place. Still not showing.....

Comment: well then maybe there's a problem in the rest of the code

Comment: Everything on the web page shows up except that. Thanks for the help. I'll get but I welcome all suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

You have to spell `src` correctly (SouRCe). You have two of its letters reversed.

This would have been picked up if you had performed some basic automated QA by using [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Additionally, I would recommend using an IDE.

Comment: I changed that and it still does work. Do you have any other suggestions.

Comment: If nothing appears still, then the image is not in the same directory as the html file is.

Comment: OK, My tags are right. I checked everything and still no image.

Comment: When you say directory you mean same folder.

Comment: Thank you. Still working on it. Still not showing. I welcome all suggestions

Comment: That was the only thing wrong with anything we can see from your question.

Answer (score 0):

your img tag was wrong,it should be

```
<img src="smile.jpg" width="120" height="90"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. Still working on it. Still not showing. I welcome all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:
Could your image *possibly* be in another folder than your  your file?
Could there be *other* divs or elements on the page that might be *"on top"* of your image?
Could your layout place things "off-screen"?
Could there be code that sets something to visibility: none?
Could you have spelled the *filename* of the image wrong?
Are you absolutely certain you force refresh your browser window when trying to load again?

Please give us the entire code; preferably as a JS-fiddle.

Comment: ..and are you sure your image extention type IS jpg, not jp, svg, png or something like that.

Comment: Where the pic is suppose to be there is a little x to the left side of the box.

Comment: This is absurd. You should check that the above sugggestions, and in addition, wether the image is corrupt in any way. Try replacing with another just for test. If that does not work, give us all the code.

Comment: oh, and btw: file extentions are case sensitive: .jpg and .JPG. Some cameras uses capital letters.

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code. Use the {}-button to display it as code. I strongly suspect your problem is a typo, or one of the alternatives I have listed in my answer.

Comment: ...and you have no separate css-sheet?

 You should change <HTML> to <!DOCTYPE html>.

And if you have checked, double-checked and triple-checked my list over things to try, I have no further suggestions.

Comment: I did as you told me still nothing. Thanks for your help. Do you think it can be something in my computer settings?

Comment: No, that is far out. Your file is a .html, I assume. If you get that little x it means the browser *reads* the image tag, but cannot *find* the image.

Comment: I had to put "file:///C:/Users/sarah/Documents/webpage/smile.jpg.JPG"

Comment: You should not have a double extension like .jpg.JPG. Please upvote and accept whatever is the right answer. And for future reference, use this as your first step in troubleshooting http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Comment: ...and one slash should be sufficient /smile.JPG

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to find it on a Linux server, the file name is case-sensitive. If you set it up and tested it and found that it tests fine on a Windows system, you will perhaps not have noticed that smile.JPG and SMILE.jpg and Smile.jpg will all be treated as though they're the same thing as smile.jpg. On a Linux host, if you call for smile.jpg and it's been stored as smile.JPG (for example), you'll get the result you're observing.

Answer (score -1):

Width and Height attributes should have units. You want them in pixels?
Try this:

```
<img src="smile.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>
```

Comment: No. The width and height CSS properties must have units. The HTML attributes must either be a pixel value expressed as a number or a percentage value expressed as a number followed by a `%` sign.

Comment: Where the pic is suppose to be there is a little x to the left side of the box.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that @Quentin. Thanks.
If there's a little x in place of the pic, doesn't this mean that the browser can't get the pic? The problem probable lies in the URL.
Either it is not pointing correctly to the image, or there's a spelling mistake (in the image filename maybe), or for some reason the server is not serving the image.
Does anything show in your browser's dev tools or the browser console?

Comment: The pic is a picture inside the same folder as my html document. It is a picture of myself. It is a jpg. Could it be something in my computer settings?

Comment: The problem was that it could not find the image. The problem did lie in the URL.

Comment: I had to put "file:///C:/Users/sarah/Documents/webpage/smile.jpg.JPG"